# Gatsby - Adding Google fonts to Gatsby site

Tags: css, gatsby, google-fonts, gatsby-plugin

I'm trying to add a Google Font (Mukta Malar) in my Gatsby site.

I've seen many articles on adding Google fonts to a Gatsby site and most of them seem to use this plugin: [gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts/).

I've used the above plugin in my site by adding it in the `gatsby-config.js` file as:

```js
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [
          {
            family: `Mukta Malar`
          },
        ],
      },
    }
  ]
```

and added the font family to my css file as well:

```css
* {
  font-family: "Mukta Malar", sans-serif;
}
```

But the Google font is not applying to the site. Is there a hidden step that I'm missing in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This plugin seems to be no longer maintained and it's part of [escalade](https://github.com/escaladesports/escalade-internal/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts) monorepo (which throws a `404` error), last commit in the core from 1 year ago.

I would suggest [`gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts/) that allows you to `display: swap` your fonts without affecting your performance. In your case:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
  options: {
    fonts: [
      `mukta malar`
    ],
    display: 'swap'
  }
}
```

Comment: It does load the Google font. But there is a flash second when the default font is visible. Is there a way to prefetch the font so that the screen doesn't flicker?

Comment: This is because of the `display: swap`. You can change the behavior but this is a way to avoid the render-block. The font is already downloaded but the CSS needs to be parsed either way and the `display: swap`loads don't block the CSS rendering and when the font is parsed, it swaps. Try `display: block` if you want to avoid the flicker.

Comment: Worked like a charm with display:block. Also learnt about font-display. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As other mentioned, include the fonts in your Gatsby project, this will be way faster!

Gatsby has a really great write up about this on their page actually.

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/using-web-fonts/

Here is a an example:

First you install the font using npm or yarn:

```
yarn add @fontsource/mukta-malar // npm install 
@fontsource/mukta-malar
```

Then in your layoutfile for the page, import the font like this:

```
import "@fontsource/mukta-malar"
```

You the reference the font in css like you would do it with any google font:

```
font-family: 'Mukta Malar', sans-serif;
```

If you only need a few specific weights or variants you can also import only parts of the package like this:

```
import "@fontsource/mukta-malar/500.css"
```

- this will only load weight 500 aka "medium" weight.

Comment: Could you format your code to show up as a snippet to improve readability of your answer?

Comment: Sorry! Is this better? I am still a bit new at posting here at stackOverflow

Comment: Yes! It's so much better! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Google fonts are available on npmjs.org with the name `typeface-XXX`XXX representing the name of the font family on the Google fonts website.

If I want to add the Poppins font on my Web site, I just need to add it on the `package.json` file:

```sh
yarn add typeface-poppins
```

Then in my site, i can use require("typeface-poppin") to use the font:

```js
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Image from "../components/image"
import SEO from "../components/seo"


require('typeface-poppins')

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <h1 style={{fontFamily: "Poppins"}}>Hi people</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
    <p>Now go build something great.</p>
    <div style={{ maxWidth: `300px`, marginBottom: `1.45rem` }}>
      <Image />
    </div>
    <Link to="/page-2/">Go to page 2</Link> <br />
    <Link to="/using-typescript/">Go to "Using TypeScript"</Link>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: `typefaces` is deprecated, it is replaced now by `fontsources`: https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource
(You even will find a notice at the typefaces webpage): https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typefaces