# Gatsby build fails google-fonts

Tags: css, gatsby, google-fonts

I seem to be running into the following error,

```
>$ gatsby build                                          
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.065s
success load plugins - 1.222s
success onPreInit - 0.019s
success delete html and css files from previous builds - 0.002s
info One or more of your plugins have changed since the last time you ran Gatsby. As
a precaution, we're deleting your site's cache to ensure there's no stale data.
success initialize cache - 0.029s
success copy gatsby files - 0.039s

 ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts" threw an error while running the onPreBootstrap lifecycle:

ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '.cache/google-fonts//fonts'



Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '.cache/google-fonts//fonts'

not finished onPreBootstrap - 7.272s
```

My gatsby-config.js looks like this,

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [
          {
            family: `Poppins`,
            variants: [`300`, `400`, `500`, `600`, `700`],
          },
          {
            family: `Fira Sans`,
            variants: [`100`, `300`, `400`, `500`, `600`, `700`],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@styled-system/theme-get": "^5.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "disqus-react": "^1.0.10",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "gatsby": "^2.24.57",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.17",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^2.5.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.3.13",
    "gatsby-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-mailchimp": "^5.2.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.28",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.27",
    "gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts": "^1.4.3",
},
```

I've tried the following but doesn't seem to work - [Gatsby - Adding Google fonts to Gatsby site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372710/gatsby-adding-google-fonts-to-gatsby-site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to some GitHub threads (https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27607) it seems to be an unresolved bug (that affects versions greater than `^2.25.1`) and they suggest using alternative packages, such as:

- [`gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts/)
- [`gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts/?=gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts)

After the proper configuration, the issue should be gone.

Keep in mind that if you are using Gatsvy `v3`, some packages may be deprecated until they are being upgraded to the new version of Gatsby.

I personally use [`gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2/) and works perfectly. You can follow the stack of the fonts in the generated `<link>` to check the loaded fonts from Google, in this case:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2`,
  options: {
    fonts: [
      {
        family: `Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700`,
      },
      {
        family: `Fira Sans:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700`,
      }
    ]
  }
},
```